# Best way to manage multiple queues in a FIFO-ish manner

Tags: .net, queue, .net-4.5, job-scheduling

I've got a UI which can queue up jobs of radically different types. At present, it does this by storing the job in the appropriate table in a database (Table-per-JobType)

My back-end process then comes along, picks up the job(s), and assuming there's an available worker (thread), uses it to execute the appropriate method for the job.

in PseudoCode:

```
While(Runnning) {
    While(Queue1.HasJobs && Workers.IdleCount > 0) {
        FirstIdleWorker.Execute(Queue1Method(Type1Job));
    }

    ...

    While(QueueN.HasJobs && Workers.IdleCount > 0) {
        FirstIdleWorker.Execute(QueueNMethod(TypeNJob));
    }
    //Wait for a job to complete or a polling timeout if queues are empty
}
```

(It's not actually that naive but it illustrates the order in which work is processed)

As you can see, this works but it doesn't take into account what order jobs were added in. This isn't a deal breaker as jobs are atomic but it is annoying from a UI perspective - eg User 1 Queues up 20 jobs of Type 2, then User 2 Queues up 1,000 jobs of Type 1. User 1 now has to wait for all User 2's jobs to complete before their (relatively) quick jobs are processed.

Jobs do have a `CreatedOn` property so determining the order isn't difficult but how best to implement a combined queue in a strongly-typed way that isn't spaghetti code?

I'm trying to avoid a "GenericJob" object with a `.CreatedOn`, `.Queue1Id`, `.Queue2Id`, `.Queue3Id` as this just feels sloppy.

While FIFO is broadly what I'm after, it's not a strict requirement - I just don't want items to be bumped forever.

Is there a pattern for this sort of thing? If not, can someone point me at a good tutorial please?

(Incidentally, these are potentially long-running jobs. I'm actually using the TPL behind the scenes to manage workers once the jobs are taken from the Queue but I do still need to manage the queue myself as there are far more jobs than I could load into memory in one go)

Comment: What's the reason that there are serveral queues? It seems that you want to merge them into a single queue anyways.

Comment: It's an internal use app that performs a number of radically different scans (different input and output. Some take domain names, others hosts and some take "Fuzzy" search terms). The work is done by totally different libraries but it's all running on the same server and rather than have N services processing jobs, I decided to combine them into one - especially since this allows me more control over combined resources usage without IPC

Comment: Mark 1 Mod 0 actually worked by having a Job with a `List<String>` input and a `JobType` which worked -ish- but resulted in confusion if it expected (say) domain names and got hostnames/IP addresses. It also only output to a CSV with some metadata and left it up to the user to collate/organise results. This time, I want the output stored in a structured way in a Db so I can generate reports, re-use old results, etc...

Comment: A generic job item shouldn't have to be so sloppy, perhaps using _abstraction_ to define the structure of common job attributes, for job control purposes. A common Process() function or similar could take over each job's specific processing requirement.

Comment: ... alternatively, using multiple workers with cleverness to start processing on job types that don't have any workers assigned to those types already... but this seems flakey to me.

Comment: @wez As mentioned in the Q, the jobs specifically have radically different inputs/outputs. Outputs shouldn't be such a problem but inputs is, (No obvious way to abstract). I agree re: flakiness of option 2 (I was thinking something similar). Perhaps each worker could have a "preferred job type" which would be taken into consideration when assigning work?

Comment: @wex actually, I take that back you may be on to something - An object with an Enum to indicate job type and a `Date` and `Id` field might be sufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poke me if I'm wrong, I hope this pseudo-code explains the Interface Abstraction okay.

An interface might look like:

```
enum JobTypes
{
    JobType1 = 0x01,
    JobType2 = 0x02,
    JobType3 = 0x03
}
interface IJob
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    JobTypes JobType { get; set; }
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    bool Complete { get; set; }
    void Process(List<object> parameters);
}
```

Each job type processor implements this interface, change and add properties to suit your needs:

```
class JobType1 : IJob
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public JobTypes JobType { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
    public void Process(List<object> parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You could then mix the job types into one list:

```
List<IJob> joblist = new List<IJob>();
```

and possibly sort them by date using lambda:

```
joblist.Sort((a, b) => DateTime.Compare(a.Date, b.Date));
```

get a list of unprocessed jobs (does not check for those busy processing*)

```
List<IJob> undone = joblist.Where(job => job.Complete == false) as List<IJob>;
```

Comment: Hi wez, glad you posted as an answer, I was just about to ask you to. That's close to what I did except that I opted to use a `JobQueue` class which is nothing more than a placeholder in the queue and stored the `CreatedOn`, `JobType` (Enum) and `Id` (The Id specific to that Job Type). I've then got a factory which takes this placeholder and instantiates the correct class to deal with it. I've done it this way as it allows me to re-query the queue repeatedly without much overhead (The queue can be modified from elsewhere so I need to keep checking the Db). Thanks

Comment: Great thinking with using the factory.

Answer (score 1):

The full answer is probably something like job-shop scheduling, since you have jobs requiring different resources or levels of resources, and you want to avoid starving short jobs. It's sort of complicated and takes some reading, but it's ultimately less work than trying to do complex scheduling ad hoc out of a single queue.

It doesn't sound like you have dependencies between jobs, so a lower-effort way would be to have queues per-user-per-job type, and then do a weighted round-robin on the queues. (I.e. take 2 jobs from Queue X for every job from Queue Y.)